# IBM Rational Application Developer 7 Websphere 6.1 not getting started while connecting over VPN

Tags: ibm-rad, websphere-6.1

Application server IBM WebShpere 6.1 is getting started and runs for longtime when connected to VPN. But, its starts fine without VPN connection. It was working fine for more than a year and suddenly facing it. Anyone come across the same issue. What is the solution to this.

Comment: Support for WAS 6.1 ended in 2013.  Consider upgrading to V8.5.5 or 9.0 to get the latest fixes and features.  For this problem, what errors are in the server logs?  What type of connection is failing over VPN?  Database, application, ???

Comment: Thanks @FRowe 

I got resolved the issue by choosing 

(SOAP)  Designed to be more firewall compatible and SOAP connecter port as 8881.

Under server connection type and admin port of sever. 

Previously it was 

RMI ( Designed to improve communication with the server) and ORB bootstrap port as 2810.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I got resolved the issue by choosing

**SOAP (Designed to be more firewall compatible and SOAP connecter port as 8881).**
Under server connection type and admin port of Sever.

Previously it was

**RMI ( Designed to improve communication with the server) and ORB bootstrap port as 2810.**